# Prestashop 1.7 Order Class: How to update the products list, recompute the shipping cost, and the VAT?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have to update an existing order. This update includes **adding/removing/updating** products (updating products would consist in changing the quantities for example), recomputing the shipping cost, and the VAT.

In the `Order` and `Product` classes, I didn't find any method to do it. How could I fulfill my goal?

Edit:

- To recompute the shipping cost, I've found:  `Order::refreshShippingCost()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this function `ajaxProcessEditProductOnOrder` in controllers/admin/AdminOrderController.

You should create a new function based on this, or you can use the existing one.